# Is $S\cup\{v_{k+1},\dots , v_n\}$ necessarily a basis of $V$?

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $V$ be a vector space over a field $\mathbb{F}$.
>
> $\{v_1,\dots ,v_n\}$ is a basis of $V$
>   $S$ is a lin. ind. subset of $V$ s.t. $|S|=k$, $k<n$.
>   $\forall i\in\mathbb{N}\quad k+1\leq i\leq n\quad v_i\notin Span(S)$
>
> Is $S\cup\{v_{k+1},\dots , v_n\}$ necessarily a basis of $V$?

*Progress*:

Yes it is and we prove by starting from $\{v_1,\dots ,v_k\}$ and adding an element from $\{v_{k+1},\dots ,v_n\}$ until we get a lin. ind. set $\{v_1,\dots ,v_n\}$ which is a basis of $V$.

*However, I don't feel like it works. Moreover, I might be wrong saying that it's a basis.*

Comment: It looks like you are ignoring $S$.

Comment: As the answer below demonstrates, the claim is false. However, what you _can_ say is that _there exists_ a subset $\mathcal{B} \subset \{v_1 \cdots v_n\}$ such that $|\mathcal{B}| = n-k$ and $S \cup \mathcal{B}$ is a basis for $V$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NO. For example : Let $n=3$ and $k=1$ and $S=\{v_2+v_3\}$.